# Getting result from Android Library Project

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-library

I created an activity in my own library project

```
intent = new Intent(context, LibraryActivity.class)
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

it does some work and returns the value in the `onActivityResult()` method. I get the result as

```
data.getExtras().get("result");
```

**Problem** is I can't able to get the result, data is null

in `LibraryActivity` I put the result as

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("result", getMessages(no));
```

**I found the solution and added to this question**

While setting result, you want to pass the intent,

> setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);

Comment: Don't post duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

`intent.putExtra("key_name", value);` allows you to pass values through the intent. So, to retrieve these values use `intent.getStringExtra("key_name");`

The Problem :

```
intent.getExtras().get("result");
```

intent.getExtras() returns a [bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)  which is null since you did not pass a bundle with the intent. You just passed a value. So when you try to retrieve an extra value from a null object it gives you the NPE.

Comment: please note that intent itself is null

Comment: Can you please post your logcat output.

Comment: nullPointerexception occurs in data.getExtras();

Comment: data.getExtras().get("result"); this line ?